# Expresso Store and SKU related product picture

Tags: expresso-store, product

Is there any way to have SKU related product image? My goal is to have changed product image on SKU change (product option change).

It looks like that I need to customize part which is responsible for a dynamic SKU display, but I'm not 100% sure and I want to avoid some overhead in that case.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally that would be case for a Store extension.

You could do a workaround by using a Grid field to add the image, in the Grid have three fields:

Image, 
SKU, 
Description

Upload your images, and add descriptions. You would need to manually type in matching SKU values in the Grid SKU field.

Once you have that set up you could use some conditionals (or perhaps JS) to bind/group the Store SKU and Grid SKU together and outur the corresponding images.